# OTC View autolayout in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, autolayout

I'm new to swiftui and swift basically, i made One-time-code screen, and here i have a problem. When i run project on my old phone (iphone 6) when keyboard appears, my textfield size changes (it gets very thin vertically). So i was wondering is there any way to add autolayout for older devices?

Here is my code

```
struct OneTimeCodeBoxes: View {
    
    @Binding var codeDict: [Int: String]
    @State var firstResponderIndex = 0
    var onCommit: (()->Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<codeDict.count) { i in
                let isEmpty = codeDict[i]?.isEmpty == true
                
                OneTimeCodeInput(
                    index: i,
                    codeDict: $codeDict,
                    firstResponderIndex: $firstResponderIndex,
                    onCommit: onCommit
                )
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: isEmpty ? 1 : 2)
                    .foregroundColor(isEmpty ? .secondary : .green))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OneTimeCodeBoxes_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OneTimeCodeBoxes(codeDict: .constant([0: "", 1: "", 2: "", 3: ""]))
            .padding()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Here is my OneTimeCodeInput part of code

```
struct OneTimeCodeInput: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextField
    
    let index: Int
    @Binding var codeDict: [Int: String]
    @Binding var firstResponderIndex: Int
    var onCommit: (()->Void)?
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        let index: Int
        @Binding var codeDict: [Int: String]
        @Binding var firstResponderIndex: Int
        
        private lazy var codeDigits: Int = codeDict.count
        
        init(index: Int, codeDict: Binding<[Int: String]>, firstResponderIndex: Binding<Int>) {
            self.index = index
            self._codeDict = codeDict
            self._firstResponderIndex = firstResponderIndex
        }
        
        @objc func textFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("textField.text!", textField.text!)
            
            guard textField.text!.count == codeDigits else { return }
            
            codeDict = textField.text!.enumerated().reduce(into: [Int: String](), { dict, tuple in
                let (index, char) = tuple
                dict.updateValue(String(char), forKey: index)
            })
            
            firstResponderIndex = codeDigits - 1
            
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                       shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                       replacementString string: String) -> Bool
        {
            print("replacementString", string)
            
            if string.isBackspace {
                codeDict.updateValue("", forKey: index)
                firstResponderIndex = max(0, textField.text == "" ? index - 1 : index)
                return false
            }

            for i in index..<min(codeDict.count, index + string.count) {
                codeDict.updateValue(string.stringAt(index: i - index), forKey: i)
                //                print(codeDict)
                firstResponderIndex = min(codeDict.count - 1, index + string.count)
            }
            
            
            return true
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        .init(index: index, codeDict: $codeDict, firstResponderIndex: $firstResponderIndex)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let tf = BackspaceTextField(onDelete: {
            firstResponderIndex = max(0, index - 1)
        })
        tf.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldEditingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        tf.delegate = context.coordinator
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad
        tf.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
        tf.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        tf.textAlignment = .center
        return tf
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = codeDict[index]
        
        if index == firstResponderIndex {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        if index == firstResponderIndex,
           codeDict.values.filter({ !$0.isEmpty }).count == codeDict.count
        {
            onCommit?()
        }
    }
    
}


extension OneTimeCodeInput {
    
    
    class BackspaceTextField: UITextField {
        
        var onDelete: (()->Void)?
        
        init(onDelete: (()->Void)?) {
            self.onDelete = onDelete
            
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        override func deleteBackward() {
            super.deleteBackward()
            
            onDelete?()
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is how it shows on Ipnone13 simulator, and it's correct. I'm trying to do same on older devices
[image]

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't have "autolayout".

Comment: then what's similar to this? is it constraints?

Comment: It's SwiftUI. :) The language itself constructs the layout. That's what your code is doing.

Comment: then why i still have this issue on old devices?

Comment: The problem is likely in the view that contains `OneTimeCodeBoxes` that you have not shown.

Comment: @Yrb i didn't understand u

Comment: Your error is probable contained in the code for `OneTimeCodeBoxes`. You have not posted the code as part of your question.

Comment: @Yrb edited and added missing part of code